Neovim nvim-cmp don't work autocompletion for path?
Plugins for cmp
  use("hrsh7th/nvim-cmp") -- completion plugin
  use("hrsh7th/cmp-buffer") -- source for text in buffer
  use("hrsh7th/cmp-path") -- source for file system paths
  use("hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lua") -- source for file system paths
  use("hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp") -- source for file system paths

Config for nvim-cmp
 -- Set up nvim-cmp.
  local cmp = require'cmp'
  cmp.setup({
    snippet = {
      -- REQUIRED - you must specify a snippet engine
      expand = function(args)
        vim.fn["vsnip#anonymous"](args.body) -- For `vsnip` users.
        -- require('luasnip').lsp_expand(args.body) -- For `luasnip` users.
        -- require('snippy').expand_snippet(args.body) -- For `snippy` users.
        -- vim.fn["UltiSnips#Anon"](args.body) -- For `ultisnips` users.
        -- vim.snippet.expand(args.body) -- For native neovim snippets (Neovim v0.10+)
      end,
    },
    window = {
      -- completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
      -- documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
    },
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
      ['<C-b>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
      ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
      ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
      ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
      ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }), -- Accept currently selected item. Set `select` to `false` to only confirm explicitly selected items.
    }),
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
      { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
      { name = 'vsnip' }, -- For vsnip users.
      -- { name = 'luasnip' }, -- For luasnip users.
      -- { name = 'ultisnips' }, -- For ultisnips users.
      -- { name = 'snippy' }, -- For snippy users.
    }, {
      { name = 'buffer' },
    })
  })

  -- Set configuration for specific filetype.
  cmp.setup.filetype('gitcommit', {
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
      { name = 'git' }, -- You can specify the `git` source if [you were installed it](https://github.com/petertriho/cmp-git).
    }, {
      { name = 'buffer' },
    })
  })

  -- Use buffer source for `/` and `?` (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
  cmp.setup.cmdline({ '/', '?' }, {
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
    sources = {
      { name = 'buffer' }
    }
  })

  -- Use cmdline & path source for ':' (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
  cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
      { name = 'path' }
    }, {
      { name = 'cmdline' }
    }),
    matching = { disallow_symbol_nonprefix_matching = false }
  })

And settings for lspconfig
-- Setup language servers.
local lspconfig = require('lspconfig')
local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()
-- require('lspconfig')['<YOUR_LSP_SERVER>'].setup {
--   capabilities = capabilities
-- }
lspconfig.lua_ls.setup {
  capabilities = capabilities
}
lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  capabilities = capabilities
}
lspconfig.volar.setup {
  capabilities = capabilities
}
lspconfig.pyright.setup {
  capabilities = capabilities
}
lspconfig.intelephense.setup {
  capabilities = capabilities,
  filetypes = { "php" },
  settings = {
    intelephense = {
      files = {
        maxSize = 1000000,
      },
      environment = {
        includePaths = {
          "/home/serii/Sites/wordpress",
          "/home/serii/Sites/advanced-custom-fields-pro",
          "/home/serii/Sites/woocommerce",
        },
      },
    },
  }
}

And now in php wordpress file i don't have path autocomplete
<div class="home-intro">
<?php echo get_template_part('template-parts/'); ?>
</div>

Thanks for answer.

Can you please execute :LspInfo and give me the output of the lines Configured servers list and [n] client(s) attached to this buffer? :)

:h i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F

ctrl+x ctrl+f it's working, thanks.

@Bog,
LspInfo
 
 Language client log: /home/serii/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
 Detected filetype:   php
 
 1 client(s) attached to this buffer: 
 
 Client: intelephense (id: 1, bufnr: [1])
  filetypes:       php
  autostart:       true
  root directory:  /home/serii/Local/lc-vite/app/public/wp-content/themes/bs-vite
  cmd:             /home/serii/.local/share/nvim/mason/bin/intelephense --stdio
 
 Configured servers list: pyright, intelephense, emmet_ls, cssls, rust_analyzer, lua_ls, tsserver, volar



Path completion in Vim is triggered by C-x C-f; see :help omnicomplete.
